Why is there no time cost to large stack allocations
I tried this quick-bench test and I'm finding that it's the same cost timewise to allocate 200 bytes as it is to allocate 2000000 bytes.

How could that possibly be?

Also post complete code(used to do the comparison) here on stackoverflow.

It's at the link. It's got quick-benchisms that won't run anywhere else

Yes, but the complete code should also be posted here on SO. We cannot rely on external sites(especially for the code part)

char buf[ N ] doesn't initialize the array elements to zero. Try changing it to char buf[ N ]{} in all three cases and you'll see the difference. Also you're not using the array. See this modified demo

Why wouldn't it be free? It's just {in,de}crementing the pointer, which is O(1).

Very little of that very large array is used. I haven't looked at the assembly generated, but is it possible the compiler sees this and optimizes?

@HolyBlackCat the operating system still might have to add new pages to the stack segment, if it grows beyond what's currently available. But, they are likely doing it in rather efficient ways.

Usually there is no direct memory allocation, the OS will start adding pages when needed. Somewhere in 1995 I did have issues with Irix (silicon graphics workstation) not doing that correctly in some boundary conditions (getting the stack to line up with page boundaries).  So yes from personal experiance I would say @ChristianStieber is correct ;)

Try larger numbers. For the heap allocation versus 200 byte malloc, a 200 MB malloc is 25 times slower, and a 1 GB malloc is 32 times slower.


Why is there no time cost to large stack allocations

Allocation need not be anything more than an accounting procedure. For stack allocation, nothing more may be necessary than changing the value of the stack pointer. Adding 2,000,000 to the value of the stack pointer does not take more time than adding 200.
Once the stack is changed, there may be consequences from that. The program, which you have not shown, may go on to use memory around the new location of the stack pointer. The first use of such memory may incur some overhead if it is in a newly used virtual memory page, as the hardware will trigger an exception, and the operating system will provide physical memory for the page. However, this occurs as the memory is used and will be much the same whether 2,000,000 or 20,000,000 bytes are allocated. Compared to 200 bytes, it might or might not be the same, as the change by 200 bytes might or might not move the stack pointer into a new page.
Attempting to use the newly allocated memory is a different matter, as the costs for reading or writing memory are generally linear in the amount of memory used (and may involve merely hardware access to memory or may involve further operating system interventions, depending on circumstances).
Allocation using malloc is much the same. The accounting will be more complicated than just changing the stack pointer, but it is still basically just examining and updating a few data structures with a low overhead time, not proportional to the amount of space allocated.

Malloc requires allocating physical memory (usually from a set of 4KB pages) and mapping into virtual address space. On a 64 bit system, a 16GB malloc will take more than than a 1KB malloc. As you noted malloca() which allocates from the stack is just a subtract.

@rcgldr: Memory allocated with malloc does not have to be mapped into virtual memory until it is used. No physical memory allocation for the allocated memory is required at the time of allocation. It can be provided on-demand when exceptions occur as the process attempts to use the memory. Some memory may be required if the operating system needs memory to manage its record-keeping of the virtual memory map. This is small compared to the memory allocated (and may be very small when “huge” pages are used).

In the case of Windows | Visual Studio, I see the memory allocated and mapped at the time of call to malloc. Page size is 4096 bytes.

@rcgldr: What Windows does is up to Windows. The C++ standard does not require malloc to behave that way. OP asked how their benchmark could possibly show about the same time to allocate 200 bytes as it does 2,000,000 bytes. The answer is the memory does not have to be mapped or initialized, and the system on which they performed the benchmark apparently behaves that way, so that is the answer. The fact some other operating system may behave different does not change the answer to the question the OP asked.

I looked into quick bench, cache sizes are level 1, 32KB, level 2, 256KB, level 3, 47 MB. For  malloc, versus 200 bytes, a 200 MB malloc takes 25 times as long, a 1GB malloc takes 32 times as long, so there is a time cost for larger sizes. I have some programs that allocate 16GB on a 64 bit system with 32GB.

char buf[ N ] leaves buf uninitialized i.e all its elements have undetermined values. So in all three test cases you're not actually initializing the array but only allocating memory.
To see the actual difference, add braces to zero-initialize the array as shown below:
//-----------vv---->added these braces for initilization
char buf[ N ]{};

Now you can see the difference in this modified demo.


That is a good point. So basically any size stack memory alloc is the same cost, as long as you don't initialize it?

@bobobobo Yes, initialization is time consuming. Allocation(without any initialization) takes almost the same time.

Uninitialized stack allocs can be O(n) too. If you compile with -fstack-protector, gcc/clang will generate a loop to touch each page of the stack allocation (to prevent jumping over a possible guard page).
